# In redux Form enforce 'name' prop of Field to be of a conform to a TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript, redux-form

Say I have a form in Redux Form that has uses an interface like so:

```
interface FormFields {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}
```

If I use redux-form's `Field` component directly I might do something like this:

```
<Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text" />
```

which is great, but has the weakness that I can put any string as the `name` prop and the compiler will not complain.

What I'd like to do is lock the `name` prop down to only the keys in my `FormFields` interface. This would probably involve wrapping the `Field` component in a parent function that has a stricter interface for Props. E.g.

```
function StrictField<F>(props: StricterFieldProps<F>) {
  return <Field {...props} />
}
```

where `StricterFieldProps` is something like:

```
interface StricterFieldProps<F> extends BaseFieldProps {
  name: keyof F
}
```

But clearly this doesn't work as there are already generics involved which will have to be passed through.

Any ideas of how to achieve this?

<sup>aside: I am aware that `name` also supports dot and array access notation for targeting nested form fields, but I'm not bothered about allowing this</sup>